# Setting a common year color between multiple ggplots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a cleaned dataset (DropBox: [[[removed - comment if you need an updated copy for working example]]]) of expenditures between 2001 and 2014.  I have three plots - a boxplot, and two scatters - that I am `grid.arrange`ing into a column for comparison.  For this reason, I'd like the years to be aligned top-to-bottom, and for each year to have a single color common between the graphs - again, for comparison.

Here is my product, so far (everything's working on this end, just unsure how to align the mappings)

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)
require(ggthemes)
require(lubridate)

options(scipen=999)

date <- exp.s$Date
amount <- exp.s$Amount
N <- exp.s$total
xy <- data.frame(date, amount, N)

#boxplot, color by year of payment
b1<-ggplot(xy, aes(x = as.factor(year(date)), amount)) + 
 geom_boxplot(aes(fill = as.factor(exp.s$start_year))) +
 scale_color_gdocs() + 
 theme_gdocs()

#jitter plot, color by year of payment
b2<-ggplot(xy, aes(x = as.factor(year(date)), amount))  + 
 geom_jitter(alpha=I(.8), aes(color=as.factor(year(date)), size = exp.s$tot)) + 
 scale_color_gdocs() + theme_gdocs()

#jitter, color by contract start year
b3<-ggplot(xy, aes(x = as.factor(year(date)), amount))  + 
 geom_jitter(alpha=I(.9), aes(color=as.factor(exp.s$start_year), size = exp.s$tot)) + 
 scale_color_gdocs() + theme_gdocs()


grid.arrange(b1, b2, b3, ncol=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)
require(ggthemes)
require(lubridate)

options(scipen=999)

#read data
exp.s <- read.csv("2001_2014_Expenditures_Cleaned_Hashed.csv")

#make same levels for 2 variables 
mylevels <- as.character(sort(unique(c(year(exp.s$Date),exp.s$start_year))))

#data prep
xy <- data.frame(
  mydate = exp.s$Date,
  mydateYYYY = factor(year(exp.s$Date),levels = mylevels),
  start_year = factor(exp.s$start_year,levels = mylevels),
  amount = exp.s$Amount,
  N = exp.s$tot)


#boxplot, color by year of payment
b1<-ggplot(xy, aes(mydateYYYY, amount,
                   fill = start_year)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_fill_identity("legend") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank())


#jitter plot, color by year of payment
b2<-ggplot(xy, aes(mydateYYYY, amount,
                   alpha=0.8,color=mydateYYYY, size = N))  + 
  geom_jitter() + 
  scale_color_identity() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank())


#jitter, color by contract start year
b3<-ggplot(xy, aes(mydateYYYY, amount,
                   alpha=0.9, color=start_year, size = N))  + 
  geom_jitter() + 
  scale_color_identity()  +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position="none") 


grid.arrange(b1, b2, b3, ncol=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thank you for this it works perfectly - and I like the colors you selected, as they really pop when using Cairo :D Thanks again!

Comment: from a spatial / design perspective, is it your opinion that I should trim most of those outliers in the boxplot, in order to let the  boxes fill more of the space, and make visual associations between the colors more readily apparent?

Comment: @D8Amonk you could use `scale_y_log10()` so smaller boxplots would be more visible, but then it would be hard to interpret.